# jQuery barrating.js – Sending id data

Tags: jquery, rating, jquery-bar-rating

I am using http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/ to set several ratings for people in a table. Everything works, except I can't 
the corresponding value from the data-attribute of the select to be passed onto the rating function so it saves the rating for the correct person.

```
$('.rating').each(function(index, value) {
    var dataId = $(this).closest('select').attr("data-rating-candidate");
    //console.log(dataId);

    $('.rating').barrating('show', {
        theme: 'bars-1to10',
        onSelect: function(rating, text, event) {
            if (typeof(event) !== 'undefined') {
                console.log( dataId );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously, only the last passed value from the attribute is used for the dataId variable. So how, do I get the correct one for the selected rating? I can't seem to be able to use $this inside the barrating selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use $this. But instead barrating have a variable called 'this' inside onSelect call back. For example my element have 'data-shop-id' attribute and then I can access it's value inside onSelect by doing this :

```
onSelect: function(value, text, event) {
                var el          = this;
                var shop_id     = el.$elem.data('shop-id');
//do your stuff here                
}
```